# Sort array/list in Perl using comma or dot for string concatenation

Tags: arrays, perl, list, hash

I have:

```
#!c:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe

use strict;
use warnings;

# Define an array
my @letters = ('b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'd');
print sort @letters , "\n";
```

Outputs: `abcdePress any key to continue . . .`
Why isn't there any line return?

I then tried using the period concatenation operator:

```
#!c:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe

use strict;
use warnings;

# Define an array
my @letters = ('b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'd');
print sort @letters . "\n";
```

Output: `5
Press any key to continue . . .`

Why does the `\n` work here, but return the array length?

Any references to official documentation would help.

Comment: Have a look at: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines
I believe that is what you are looking for.
Or perhaps even: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do

```
print sort @letters . "\n";
```

you are really evaluating `@letters` in a scalar context and appending a newline, and then sorting that array. Since the array is of length 5, you get the number 5.

Try it like this:

```
my @letters = ('b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'd');
print sort(@letters . "\ntest");
```

And you'll output:

```
5
test
```

The behavior of `sort` is undefined in scalar context. So you **cannot** do:

```
my @letters = ('b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'd');
print sort(@letters) . "\n";
# This doesn't produce any output
```

You probably want to do something like this:

```
my @letters = ('b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'd');
print join(",", sort(@letters)) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

---

For the first scenario, you are appending `\n` to the list of letters, and then sorting it. So it ends up at the beginning. Here's an example:

```
my @letters = ('b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'd');
print sort @letters , "\n", 1, 2, 3;
```

Outputs:

```
# It outputs a newline and then the characters:

123abcde
```

---

In general, it is useful to use parentheses to clear on what behavior you want to get.

```
my @letters = ('b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'd');
print sort(@letters), "\ntest";
```

Outputs:

```
abcde
test
```